# How to render in blender with compositing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I have started using blender for a couple of weeks now and I got familiar with the compositing interface. The problem is if I change the color from, lets say, gray to red through compositing it will still render as grey. How do I fix it so that it will composite?

Answer (score 4):

I would check 2 things first:

1. Do you have the Compositing checkbox in the Post Processing panel under Render settings checked? If not the render process will bypass the compositor.

[image]

2. Do you have your compositing nodetree connected to the Composite node? If you only have the Viewer node hooked up you won't see the effects of your composite.

[image]

Comment: I saw this question in the review, and did not realize it already had an answer. good one.

Comment: Yes I have done both of those things they dont pop up in the render though.

Comment: Ok, probably be best if you post your blend file then.

Comment: I think it would have been to clarify in comments before answering.